# Android App crashes on Button running thread pressed | Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http

I am creating an app to check whether the given address of a server is valid or not. It sends request to a server when Connect button is pressed. If request succeed it is valid if not invalid ...
But I am having an error when I run a thread. I cant run it on Computer caz having issues enabling ADV but here is my code.

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Server Address"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addressInput"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.869" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addressInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Enter your server address"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addressBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Connect"
        android:onClick="onAddressButtonClick"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addressInput"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.065" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.naveed.youtubestream;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button addressBtn;
    private EditText addressInput;
    private String serverAddress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addressBtn = findViewById(R.id.addressBtn);
        addressInput = findViewById(R.id.addressInput);

    }

    private boolean checkAddress(String address){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(address);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if(connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                return true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        return false;
    }

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                if(checkAddress(serverAddress)){
                    //TODO --> Set new Layout
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server address was valid.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else {
                    addressInput.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid server address.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };


    public void onAddressButtonClick(View view) {
        try{
            serverAddress = addressInput.getText().toString();
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.naveed.youtubestream">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: And the exception is?

Comment: @akortex91 
it doesnt show any exception i am using it on directly mobile i cant run it on virtual env. 
i have issue with ADV it doesnt let me create virtual env

Comment: I'd try and get it to run on an emulator, but you can still read the logcat of a real device.

Comment: please share error where run